# Mongoose Validation Based on Other Fields

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider the following schema for saving time intervals in Mongoose:

```
let dateIntervalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  begin: { type: Date, required: true  },
  end: { type: Date, required: true }
})
```

How can I ensure that `end` is always greater than or equal to `begin` using [Mongoose Validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if Mongoose has built-in validators for this, but something as small as the following can be used.

```
startdate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    // default: Date.now
},
enddate: {
    type: Date,
    validate: [
        function (value) {
            return this.startdate <= value;
        }
    ]
},
```